# Fetching Questions - Insert All rows to my table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question in fetching, I want to insert data into my table.

If I echo I get all the data, but when inserting I checked in my table and it only shows 1 piece of data per column instead of multiple rows of data. Assuming its all 13 rows, I get only 1.

I have used this method in my other projects with no problem, why is it different now?

The query only displays 2 columns: Child and Catalog, I need them to be inserted into my table.

```sql
select CHILD_RLI, CATALOG_ITEM_NAME From myDB; -- example query
```

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) 
{


    $crli                       = $row["CHILD_RLI"];
    $catalog_item_name          = $row["CATALOG_ITEM_NAME"];
    $str_catalog_name           =  mysql_real_escape_string($catalog_name);

    $catalogqry = "INSERT into rli_tbl
                                    (crli,catalog_name) 
                                    VALUES 
                                    ('".$crli."','".$str_catalog_name."')";

    mysql_query($catalogqry);   

}
```

Comment: You should add error handling and you should escape your data or use prepared statements. Your data could be breaking your query.

Comment: Please make the question title descriptive to what you are asking.

Comment: Please be noticed that `mysql_*` extension are already deprecated; You should move to `MySQLi` or `PDO` and (more importantly) prepared statement and variable binding, instead of stuffing everything into a SQL query.

Comment: found my culprit. it was % sign in my data.